# When I can reverse the logical operators?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I heard say that is logically equivalent to say it:
$$\neg (p \vee q) = p \land q$$

So every time you have a negation operator in front can make a "distributive" altering the operator from within? And if $\neg(p \vee \neg q)$ then result is $p \land \neg q$? Can anyone give some examples?

Answer (score 4):

No, that does not work. What does work is De Morgan's law:

$$ \neg(p\lor q) \iff \neg p \land \neg q $$
Your formulation is missing the negations on the right-hand side.

If you want, you can *think* of this as "negation distributes over $\land$ and $\lor$, **except** that it changes each of them to the other". I'm not entirely sure that's a helpful way of thinking, but whatever works for you ...

Comment: Thanks. Is there any example of this situation?

Comment: @DanielaMarquesdeMorais: What do you mean by example? You can check it for $(p,q)$ being (true,true) or (false,true) or (true,false) or (false,false) -- that covers all the possibilities.

Comment: Example? This short of thing?? "It isn't true that he came first or second" is equivalent to "He didn't come first and didn't come second".

Answer (score 2):

If I can add something:

The [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) holds exclusively for **conjunction** and **disjunction**, thus having something to do with their **[duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(mathematics))**. It is a pair of laws, expressed informally as follows:

> The negation of a conjunction is the disjunction of the negations.
>
> The negation of a disjunction is the conjunction of the negations.

Symbolically:

$$¬(p\land q) \Leftrightarrow ¬p\vee ¬q$$
$$¬(p∨q)\Leftrightarrow ¬p∧¬q$$
But as Makholm observed, your formulation neglects the inner negations in the RHS.

Answer (score 1):

Example, as requested...

Suppose I want to know what is the domain of the function
$$
\frac{1}{x^2-4x+3}
$$
That is, I want to find all the $x$ where that denominator is not zero.
So I factor the denominator.  $x^2-4x+3=(x-1)(x-3)$.
When is it zero?  Either $x=1$ or $x=3$.  So when is it nonzero?
$$
\neg\;\big(x=1\;\lor\;x=3\big)
$$
That is, (by the principle explained in Henning's answer)
$$
x\neq 1\;\land \;x\neq 3
$$
In order to belong to the domain, $x$ must be different from $1$ and different from $3$.